Why can blowing compressed air through a vertical glass tube suck up small objects from the tube?

I saw a video on a famous website about a vertical glass tube. When a compressed air nozzle is used to blow the upper end of the glass tube, small objects at the bottom of the tube will be sucked up and blown away.
The creator of the video explained that this is caused by the Bernoulli principle, as' high speed leads to low pressure '.

I am very skeptical about this explanation because I have noticed that compressed air is blowing diagonally upwards. I have tested that if air is blown horizontally from the plane of the glass tube mouth, it will not be able to suck up small objects in the tube.
Blowing air diagonally upwards can suck up small objects, which is equivalent to the mouth of a glass tube being the upper surface of a wing, and blowing air diagonally upwards is equivalent to giving this mouth an angle of attack. This causes the air at the mouth of the glass tube to be pulled upwards due to its viscosity, resulting in a low pressure inside the vertical tube.
Is my suspicion and explanation correct?

This seems reminiscent of a flute (with airflow running at a slight angle across a hole in a tube to move air inside the tube). Have you looked into why fluted work? It might be related.

Entrainment and the associated terms might also prove useful for searching the literature.
